# Execution failed for task ':react-native-action-sheet:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I keep getting this error when I run

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-action-sheet:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
35 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 34 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

the command `npx react-native run-android`:

I tried to run the app on a virtual device

Comment: The error says some info. Make sure to check whether the emulator is not running or not connected (incase of the physical device)